# two piped process slowdown execution after few time

Tags: bash, pipe, buffer, real-time

I've two piped process :

```
gnome-terminal -e ./script1 | ./script2.py
```

That I use for "real time" process (my script2.py control motors by serial port) ... It work fine but after a short time it slowdown a lot...

Is there any way to "flush" or to skip some data passing from the pipe to keep my "realtime" as short as possible ? (and get my motors reacting as fast as possible to any change coming from my script1)

thanks a lot !

Comment: Why is gnome-terminal even part of this?

Comment: It just to be able to print some output in this terminal and monitor what happen....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused. The above command will start a new instance of `gnome-terminal` and run `./script1` inside it, and it will also run `./script2.py` inside the original terminal. Additionally, the standard input of `./script2.py` will be fed all the data collected from the output of the `gnome-terminal -e ./script1` command, and *not* `./script1`. So you are giving `./script2.py` the wrong data. In fact, `gnome-terminal` typically does not produce any output (actually, it may print some stuff in its `stderr`), so your are giving `./script2.py` no data.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but I do not understand very well, so from where are coming data received in script2.py ? if I just do ./script1 | ./script2.py, it would work ? thanks !

Comment: Yes, `./script1 | ./script2.py` would result in the output of `./script1` being fed into `./script2.py` as its input.

Comment: what if i have script.sh then do gnome-terminal ./script.sh and in this script.sh I do @#!/bin/bash
{
cd /home/therightplace; ./script1 | ./script2.py } || {notify-send "not working"}

Comment: Yes, that would work. You can also do something like `gnome-terminal -x bash -c './script1 | ./script2.py'` in order to avoid the auxiliary script. I still don't understand why you need `gnome-terminal`. You have a terminal where you run the `./script1 | ./script2.py`, why not just use that terminal? Is this for some kind of a launcher for your desktop environment?

Comment: exactly I launch it from a .desktop !

Comment: but when i used the last describe solution i still have the same problem... it as fast as it should do for 10 second and then slow down critically. I don't understand if it come from the buffer of the pipe or from the way of reading data in python. I'm a beginner lot of thing I do not understand yet...

Comment: Then there is issue with one of the 2 scripts. Try to run `./script1` by itself to is if it produces the expected output. Then run `./script1 | cat` to see if going through a pipe affects it somehow. Then run it again, this time collecting its output to a file, e.g. `./script1 > /tmp/foo` (let it run for a few minutes and then kill it), and then run `./script2.py < /tmp/foo` to see if that works.